# How to call an external contract function using custom Struct from typescript

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, struct

I have this basic contrat:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Greeter {
    struct Greeting {
        uint8 id;
        string text;
    }

    Greeting[] public greetings;

    string private greeting;

    constructor(string memory _greeting) {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function setGreetings(Greeting[] calldata _greetings) external {
        for (uint16 i = 0; i < _greetings.length; i++) {
            greetings.push(_greetings[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and I try to call `setGreetings` from `ethers.js`:

```js
const Greeter = await ethers.getContract("Greeter")
await Greeter.setGreetings([[0, "Hello, Hardhat!"]]);
```

but I am receiving:

```
Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=0, expectedCount=1, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.5.0)
```

though I do manage to call the `setGreeting` with a string input:

```js
await Greeter.setGreeting("Hello, Hardhat!");
expect(await Greeter.greet()).to.equal("Hello, Hardhat!");
```

Comment: Interestingly enough it works for me. You can also use an array of objects. E.g. `setGreetings([{ id: 0, text: "Test"}])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code as a test for setGreetings:

```
import { BigNumber } from "ethers";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

describe("Greeter", function () {
  it("Should set greetings", async function () {
    const Greeter = await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
    const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, world!");
    await greeter.deployed();

    const greetings = {
      id: BigNumber.from(0),
      text: "Hello, Hardhat!",
    }
    const setGreetingsTx = await greeter.setGreetings([greetings]);
    // wait until the transaction is mined
    await setGreetingsTx.wait();
  });
});
```